# postgresql - group by number and return highest value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

my SQL table looks like this

```
+------+--------+
| RANK |  ID    |
+------+--------+
| 1    | 234    |
| 2    | 234    |
| 3    | 234    |
| 1    | 421    |
| 2    | 421    |
+------+--------+
```

I'd like to group it by id and return highest rank. I don't know how to do that, my code not works.

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY ID WHERE max(RANK)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close:

```
SELECT ID, max(RANK) FROM table GROUP BY ID
```

This answer assumes you want the following result:

```
+------+--------+
| RANK |  ID    |
+------+--------+
| 3    | 234    |
| 2    | 421    |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: your results is backwards :P

Comment: @KevinMee I know, it was a copy and paste job and I wasn't going to take the time to move the columns.  In my opinion the aggregate columns should come after the selected columns.  If we really want to get technical it also wouldn't have the column title RANK

Answer (score 1):

Another method is `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id, rank desc;
```

The advantage of `distinct on` is that you can easily get all columns in the row, not just the `rank` column.